# Get data from list with multiple rows with unique ID on Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently using google sheets for my project. I have an excel workbook containing multiple sheets. The task here is to create a summarized format of all sheets for a certain time period.

The output should look like this:

[image: desired output]

My current problem is getting data from a sheet with multiple rows that have the same identifier. This is sheet number 1, **I already got all the data that I need from here**:

[image: sheet 1]

But in sheet 2, I need to be able to extract the status from this sheet for the summary:

[image]

I tried to use an IF ELSE statement with a VLOOKUP function but to no avail.

(**NOTE: I cannot share my sheet due to sensitive information. Refer to sample** For context, the sheets come from a 10 year old website.)

Comment: Hi, @player0. Unfortunately I can't share a copy of my sheet. It contains important data that should not be shared anywhere. That's why I only added a sample version. :)

Comment: I need to get the status listed in 'Status Sheet', I was able to get what I need from 'Person Sheet'.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A16:A18&B16:B18&C16:C18, {A7:A12&C7:C12&D7:D12, E7:E12}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]